# How to provide path in File constructor in android?

Tags: android, file

I am trying to know whether the path I am mentioning is the path of file or folder.
Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File f=new File("F:/Office/A.txt");


        boolean b=f.isFile();
        Toast.makeText(this,""+b,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

But it if giving false inspite of the fact that I am giving the right path. The same code in eclipse is giving true but in Android Studio is giving false. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String s = f.getAbsolutePath();'
```

then switch your Toast to this:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

that way the Toast will show you the path, and you can proceed from there

Comment: why is it that in eclipse i am getting true but in android studio i am getting false